M1 MacBook Pro randomly initiating sleep in loop
I have a MacBook Pro, M1 Pro with macOS 14.5. It randomly triggers the sleep mode in loop. When it does, I can see the following logs:
Entering DarkWake state due to 'Thermal Emergency Sleep'
<PMCallback> System Will Sleep
PMRD: sleep reason Thermal Emergency Sleep
Entering Sleep state due to 'Thermal Emergency Sleep'
[SMC: ermalPressureCC.cpp:113] SMC Thermal pressure initiated Sleep
PMRD: Thermal overtemp message received!

The problem will presist after I restart, even in Safe Mode. I must shutdown the system and close the lid for a minute to have it back to normal.
I'm trying to resolve the issue with Apple's customer service but so far, they only asked me to resintall my system from scratch which didn't help.

Looks like a bad temperature sensor is giving spurious data. If reinstalling the OS was no help, it must be a HW problem.

I’ve had the same experience with the MacBook Pro 14 M3. I went to the Apple Store, where they found no issues. They replaced the logic board, but surprisingly, the problem still persists
